# Understanding the use of pdist in combination with mdscale

Tags: matlab, scale, cluster-analysis, pdist

I am working on a clutering problem.

I have a set of 100 `observatons`. Each observation is described by 3 features.
I have to cluster these observations in 2 groups (I have a label for each observation).

Before clustering the observations I computed first the `pdist` between observations and then I used the mdscale function in MATLAB to go back to 3 dimensions.
I used the `transformed_observation` as input of a kmean clustering algorithm getting better clustering results (i.e. the clusters match with the labels) if compared to using the original observations. 
Anyone can explain me why??? I just tried...

Here you can find my steps...

```
% select the dimensions of my features
dimensions = 3;

% generate an example data set
observations = rand(100,dimensions);

% if yes use the combination of pdist + mdscale
use_dissimilarity = 'yes';

if strcmp(use_dissimilarity,'yes')
  %compute pdist between features
  dissimilarity = pdist(observations,@kullback_leibler_divergence);
  %re-transform features in 3 dimensions                             
  transformed_observations = mdscale(dissimilarity,dimensions);
else
  transformed_observations = observations;
end

%cluster observations 
numbercluster = 2;
[IDX, clustercentroids] = kmeans(transformed_observations, numbercluster,...
                    'emptyaction','singleton',...
                    'replicates',11,'display','off');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdist` computes the pairwise distances (using KL-Divergence).

`mdscale` (Multidimensional scaling) will now try to embed the distances in an *Euclidean* vector space, such that they are best preserved.

K-means **only** works with squared Euclidean distances (and a few other Bregman divergences).

So it is in my opinion an error that Matlab allows you a few other distances:

> 'sqeuclidean' (default) | 'cityblock' | 'cosine' | 'correlation' | 'hamming'

It is not surprising that this worked better if KL-Divergence is appropriate for your data set, because this construct allows using k-means on (an approximation of) KL-Divergence.

Comment: is it possible to change the distance in the MATLAB kmean to compare the results? if yes how?

Comment: Let me repeat this: K-means only works with squared Euclidean distances.

Comment: :) OK thanks. any clustering method that handles KL divergence as distance metric?

Comment: Any distance-based clustering. Hierarchical clustering and DBSCAN for example.

Comment: Hi @Anony-Mousse, would you have time to have a chat with me? I'd really appreaciate!